# Update preinstalled pip on macos

Tags: macos, installation, python, anaconda, pip

I was going to install anaconda on mac to use python via spyder. Now, in terminal I noticed that my mac already has python 2 and python 3.7.3 installed. So I figured that I wouldn't need anaconda anymore.

Then, I tried to install numpy via pip which gave me this message:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/3.7'*
>
> Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
>   You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 20.2b1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.*

Using

`pip install --upgrade pip --user`

worked but after trying to install numpy again with --user I got this:

> WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
>   Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
>   To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
>   Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
>   Collecting numpy
>     Using cached numpy-1.18.5-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (15.1 MB)
>   Installing collected packages: numpy
>     WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.7 are installed in '/Users/me/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
>     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.*

To avoid issues I uninstalled pip with

```
python3 -m pip uninstall pip
```

and uninstalled numpy which I think reverted everything back to normal.

Now, I was also able to do a user install of numpy without the path issues. But my question now is: how do I update the preinstalled pip? Would it be better to install python via homebrew or get anaconda and would that come with its on pip?